# Why is PHImageRequestOptions.progressHandler never called?

Tags: ios, photokit

Code:

```
    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.version = .Current
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .Opportunistic
    requestOptions.resizeMode = .None
    requestOptions.networkAccessAllowed = true
    requestOptions.progressHandler = {
        (progress, error, stop, info) in

        print(progress, info)
    }

    let imageManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
    imageManager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: requestOptions) {
        …
    }
```

`progressHandler` is never called, not even for an image that takes 16 second to download. Why? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Perhaps try `.HighQualityFormat` instead? It may be the `.Opportunistic` doesn't report progress...? I've never tried this. Also 16 seconds is not really very long, esp. if you are receiving intermediate images as we go along.

Comment: @matt Just tried that, no help.

Comment: I've honestly never tried this feature (the `progressHandler`). I just assumed it worked. :(

Comment: I see from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643440/hide-uiprogressview-after-fetch-for-phasset-is-completed-and-progress-finished-a that it does (or did) sometimes get called. Notice that he's stepping out to the main thread. Could that be the problem? `print` is not thread-safe so perhaps it would help if you tried that. Grasping at straws here...!

Comment: I don't think that's the reason, because I have a breakpoint there and it's never hit.

Comment: Well, a breakpoint on a background thread is a tricky thing. It's worth at least _trying_ to get on the main thread in your progress handler and see what happens...!

Comment: Tried dispatching to main queue, still no.

Comment: May I assume you're testing on an actual device? It seems to me you've done everything you can do; you should file a bug with Apple and see what they have to say.

Comment: Yes, tested on 2 devices, 1 with iCloud Photo Library on, 1 off. I'm filing radar now.

Comment: Have you try to replace the `PHImageManagerMaximumSize` to something like `CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight)`? This is weird, but in my use cases, the progressHandler is always called.

Comment: @Jonny tried, the same. BTW, `pixelWidth` and `pixelHeight` are unusable due to [radar 21045111](http://openradar.appspot.com/21045111).

Comment: I copy and paste your code into one of my Swift 2 project, and it works just fine: `progressHandler` called multiple times, and photo downloaded. Test with photo store in my iCloud Photo Library.

Comment: I didn’t met the problem your radar described. But once a while (iOS 8) I use `pixelWidth` and `pixelHeight` to check whether an image is screenshot, I found my photos synced from Photo Stream are not full-size, some of their resolution are 2048*1536 and it match the iPad screenshot resolution.

Comment: @Jonny so it may be data dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The `progressHandler` will only get called when the Photo Library needs to download a big asset from iCloud. If it's not big enough, or if it is already stored / cached on the device, it won't be called.

Try to put these options in your request:

```
let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
requestOptions.networkAccessAllowed = true
requestOptions.resizeMode = .exact
requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
```